# Export hierarchical data into XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

Our database contains hierarchical "items". Every item has detail information inside a separate table. E.g. an item could be a folder or a file. Now I would like to export children of an item to XML. For performance reasons I would like to do this inside a SP. Of course, it's possible to write a cursor-based SP, but cursors tend to be slow. Much better are **CTE** (with ...) and **FOR XML**, but I don't know how to combine CTE and FOR XML including the detail table information.

DDL

```
create table items (
   itemid integer,
   parent_itemid integer
)

create table folder (
   folderid integer,
   itemid integer,
   foldername varchar(50),
   [..]

create table file (
   fileid integer,
   itemid integer,
   filename varchar(50),
   [..]
```

XML Export

```
<folder id="1" foldername="Top-Folder">
 <folder id="2" foldername="Sub-Folder">
   <file id="10" filename="Subdoc.doc"/>
 </folder> 
 <file id="10" filename="Doc1.doc"/>
 <file id="11" filename="Doc2.doc"/>
</folder>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help: [Create XML Files Out Of SQL Server With SSIS And FOR XML Syntax](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/create-xml-files-out-of-sql-server-with-)

Comment: Very interesting, especially the part where keywords in the stored proc made it "just work".  When I got to the clickey/dialoguey part, my eyes kind of glazed over, as I'm not familiar with the product (and I wonder how to commit mouse clicks into revision control)

Comment: save the BIDS project  in  Subversion or just the .dtsx file which is just XML anyhow

Answer (score 1):

If the data will fit into memory, export the 3 tables (relevant chunks) into your favorite programming language, then assemble the tree.  Or, dump the tables into text files, such as .CSV format, then scan those.

I would use Perl, but Ruby or Python would probably be good choices as well.  Or your own language of choice / necessity.

Escape from the database, and the rest should be fairly straight forward.  Other than the "moment of extraction" aspect, reporting dumps don't need transactions.  Get the data out, then chew on it at your leisure.